Convert APNS token to FCM device registration token using Firebase Admin SDK
Now that the legacy Firebase APIs are being deprecated, it appears this might include the Instance ID Server APIs.
We are currently using the Instance ID Server APIs 'batchImport' method to convert APNS tokens to FCM device registration tokens on the back-end.
Is it using the Firebase Admin SDK to do the same thing? To convert an APNS token to an FCM device registration token? Or is it even necessary anymore to be able to send a push-notification to an iOS device using the Admin SDK? Can we use the APNS token directly?
Thanks —

We use this endpoint:
string url = "https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1:batchImport";

Per the FAQ, we can continue to call batchImport but we will need to use an OAuth 2.0 access token.
When the legacy FCM APIs are disabled using the Google Cloud Admin Console, we receive the following error message from the Instance ID Server API when trying to use the Server Key:

The HTTP request code to the batchImport remains the same except that we need to add an OAuth token instead of the FCM Server Key:
var access_token = string.Empty;
try
{
    var app = FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
    {
        Credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("service-account-file.json")
    });
    access_token = app.Options.Credential.UnderlyingCredential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync().Result;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error Creating Firebase App: " + ex.Message);
}

// Add header access_token_auth
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("access_token_auth", "true");

// Set OAuth Access Token in Authorization header
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", access_token);


Does this still work after July 2024? I'm getting the error: "Not authenticated or unauthorized." What scope should I add to perform the batchImport (APNS token registration)?

@SaliniL Were you able to solve this issue?? Even im facing the same problem. Kindly help.

@SalmanRiyaz Yes. The issue was resolved by including access_token_auth: true in the header.
